# Оптимизация квадратичной функции Python 3.6

Tags: python-3.x, scipy

Доброго времени суток!
Столкнулся со следующей проблемой: необходимо найти решение квадратичной функции

w*H*w^T -> min

s.t. 0.8>= w >=0;
     sum(w) = 1;

где:

w (1,N)

H (NxN)

Преподаватель посоветовал метод внутренней точки. В SciPy есть только симплекс метод, однако он для задач линейного программирования (можно конечно привести функцию к линейному виду, но преподаватель хочет именно метод внутренней точки). Поиски в сети свелись к тому, что либо использовать SLSQP из SciPy или какие то сторонние пакеты, типа CVXOPT, которые не желают ставится на Python 3.6. Прошу помочь с реализацией метода внутренней точки, буду очень благодарен за Ваши советы!

Comment: Что получилось до сих пор? Добавте ваш код.

Comment: https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/7128 - обратите внимание на ссылки

Comment: спасибо большое, буду пробовать делать с помощью SciPy